# CSS stylesheets are not loaded in internet explorer 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, stylesheet

My environment is Rails 3.2.8, and all my stylesheets are found in app/assets/stylesheets in `.css.scss` format. I'm also using Bootstrap-sass for my application.

The stylesheets do not seem to be loaded at all in internet explorer, and I haven't found a solution after some research.

I provide one css file for example:

***File:** posts.css.scss*

```
$myFontFamily: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
$baseFontFamily: $myFontFamily;

@import 'bootstrap';

body {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

In IE9, font, body background, font color are not at all affected by this stylesheet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the css and just put `posts.scss` and I'm assuming all `config.assets` are set correctly too. i.e., you didn't mess with them.